# ExpandableListView with a variable number of levels

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview, android-xml

I'm trying to create an ExpandableListView that has a variable number of levels, like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5QK.png

I've followed this example to create an ExpandableListView with just one level of children:

https://gist.github.com/bowmanb/4052030

Code:

```
public class SavedTabsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_tabs, null);
        ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        elv.setAdapter(new SavedTabsListAdapter());
        return v;
    }

    public class SavedTabsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };

        private String[][] children = {
            { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
            { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
            { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
            { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
        };

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
            return children[i].length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int i) {
            return groups[i];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
            return children[i][i1];
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
            return i1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(SavedTabsFragment.this.getActivity());
            textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(SavedTabsFragment.this.getActivity());
            textView.setText(getChild(i, i1).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

How can I create an ExpandableListView that has a variable number of levels? Is an ExpandableListView even the best option?

Comment: Anyone got any answers?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html) explains about 3 level expandable list. Hopefully this helps.

The basic idea is, the first-level list is backed by an `ExpandableListAdapter`. The child views generated by this adapter are `ExpandableListAdapters` themselves that provide the second-level groups and the eventual child elements.

Comment: I'm looking for a variable number of levels, meaning it can be 1 level or 20 level. Also, I feel that post might be a bit dated since it's almost 4 years old.

Comment: Well i think to achieve what you want with just `ExpandableListView` will not a be a efficient solution. It will make things messy.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm looking for guidance.